# Is it possible to do a job with someone who has already done it?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

All my friends have completed the Fleeca job but I haven't yet.

Is it still possible to get their help for the job?

Comment: You could simply try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rejoin any job you've completed again as a member and complete the mission as often as you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can join any heist whenever (even if you don't have the high end apartment or lvl 12), you can also replay jobs after you have played them all from the heist board(this requires the high end apartment). After replaying a job it becomes unavailable for a while few real life hours so you can't spam replay one heist this only applies to hosting a job, you can still join 5 fleeca jobs in a row but you cannot host them in a row.

E: to clarify the replay I think you need to host all the jobs before you get the replay option on the board. Also if you are in the middle of say Prison break heist and you want to host a fleeca job you can call Lester to cancel the current heist and replay the ones you hosted earlier.

Comment: Uhm. That's wrong. I played this prison break heist (where you have to rescue rashkowsky) 3 times in a row without any time limits.

Comment: Hosting the job has a cooldown, it gets greyed out and says "This heist was played recently"

Comment: Ah hosting. You said after replaying it, I thought you also meant if you joined as a member.

Comment: Yes, my bad was not clear I will edit it into my answer.